# Trying to connect to Google Profiles API (Contacts for domain) using JavaJascript

Tags: javascript, google-api

I'm trying to get connected to the Domain profiles but there is no Javascript library for this.

I've tried so many things and just can't get it to work.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var oauthToken = gapi.auth.getToken();
xhr.open('GET',
   'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/profiles/domain/ditotest.com/full');
   xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization','Bearer ' + oauthToken.access_token);
   xhr.setRequestHeader('Gdata-version', '3.0');
xhr.send(null);

console.log(xhr.status);
```

This errors:

```
Uncaught Error: InvalidStateError: DOM Exception 11 index.html:102
OPTIONS https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/profiles/domain/ditotest.com/full 405 (Method Not Allowed) index.html:100
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/profiles/domain/ditotest.com/full. Origin https://googledrive.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. index.html:1
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can't do a XMLHttpRequest to another domain (crossdomain). 
You would have to try to use JSONP but not sure if that API accepts the parameter &callback=

So client side, very tough.

What you could do, is "proxy it", something I normally do when I need information in the browser from other domains.
Create a server script (php for example) which calls the remote URL and make the javascript call the local server script.

Good luck!